# What is the structure of impact.js level objects?

Tags: javascript, impactjs

In the impact.js framework, what is the structure of level objects produce by the Weltmeister level editor ?
The most information I was able to find on this is the documentation for [ig.game.loadlevel](http://impactjs.com/documentation/class-reference/game#loadlevel), but it is very limited. In particular what is the meaning of the conent of a `layer`'s `data` property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example from the docs:

```
{
    entities: [
        {type: "EntityClassName", x: 64, y: 32, settings: {}},
        {type: "EntityClassName", x: 16, y: 0, settings: {}},
    ],
    layer: [
        {
            name: "background1",
            tilesetName: "media/tiles/biolab.png",
            repeat: false,
            distance: 1,
            tilesize: 8,
            foreground: false,
            data: [
                [1,2,6],
                [0,3,5],
                [2,8,1],
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

The level object has 2 sections, the `entities` and `layers`, both of which are arrays. The entities array contains entities that will spawned during level load. In the example above this is equivalent to calling `ig.game.spawnEntity(EntityClassName, 64, 32, {})`

The objects in the `layers` array create either an `ig.BackgroundMap` or an `ig.CollsionMap`, depending on the name of the map. If the name is `"collision"`, then the game will create a `ig.CollisionMap` at `ig.game.collisionMap`. If it's anything else, then it will create an `ig.BackgroundMap` and add it to the `ig.game.backgroundMaps` array.

The `data` property of the `layer` structure is the tile map itself. The array determines which tile from the tileset to draw.